# Super key not working in 20.04

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

After the recent update I have lost both my sound and the Super key. Slightly different from the other Super key issues listed here as I only have one keyboard loaded - English UK. I checked the keyboard layout in 'Settings - Language and Region' and the keyboard matches up. However in the keyboard layout various of the keys are greyed out. Since I have not been into the keyboard layout diagram for years I can't remember if they should be grey or not. So my questions:

1.) should the keys be greyed out and if not what can I do to get them 'ungreyed'?
2.) Any other Super key solutions that don't involve the bug and multiple keyboards?

(I'll keep trying to fix the sound and complain elsewhere about that)

UPDATE

Events have superseded this issue. First I thought my hard disc had died so I popped it out, put in a new one then booted 20.04 LTS clean download from a thumb drive. Everything seemed OK so I checked the old drive - it had a few sectors out but was otherwise OK. Then I tried to recover the data. The second disc then seemed to crash and I can't even get into the BIOS to relaunch from the thumb drive again. I have lost faith with 20.04 LTS and am going back to Windows. 20.04 LTS is a deeply flawed build with too many legacy faults and life is way too short. In the past few days I have had to deal with missing super keys, over heating issues (yes, I checked all the hardware -including the sensors - all good), vanishing sound and a total inability to connect my printer. Now total OS failure.

I am going to wipe the second disc and start again at some point but, frankly, I am not sure if it is worth the effort.

Comment: If you run xev in a terminal and press the super key, do you get any output? If yes, please add it to your question.